# Session limit exceeded on domain controller?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

I have a Server 2003 machine that runs a number of scheduled tasks as a particular domain user. Every couple of weeks, the user seems to lose its home directory (normally C:\documents and settings\username), and changes to (C:\documents and settings\Default User). This causes a number of jobs to fail, as it needs settings from the 'username' home directory.

In an attempt to diagnose this, I've fired up ProcMon during execution of the jobs and discovered that as soon as the job is run, a connection is initiated to \DOMAINCONTROLLER\PIPE\samr, impersonating the DOMAIN\USER that the scheduled tasks is set to run as, but with a result code of 0xC00000ce. I've learned that 0xC00000ce translates to 'too many sessions'. The only resolution that we've come up with so far is to restart the workstation service on the DC, which purges the existing sessions.

Does anyone have any experience with this? It seems as if sessions are not getting purged from the domain controller.

Thanks in advance.